# How to add random letters to a filename?

Tags: php

I have developed a form where a user can login and upload files, but we came across an issue where if the filename is the same it overwrites.

So what I am trying to implement is an upload where it either renames the file or adds additional characters to the filename, please see below my code.

```
if ($_GET['ul'] == 1) {
    $target_path = "../uploads/documents/";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadfile1']['name']); 

    $fname = $_FILES['uploadfile1']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = $_FILES['uploadfile1']['name'];

    $extensions = array('xls','pdf','PDF','doc','DOC','docx','DOCX','jpg','JPG','xlsx');
    $extension = strtolower( pathinfo( $filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );

    if (in_array($extension, $extensions)) {
        move_uploaded_file($fname, $target_path);
        echo $filename;
    } else {
        echo 'Sorry this file type cant be uploaded.';
    }
}
```

Comment: append timestamp with filename.

Comment: its its better to append timestamp

Comment: Thanks for all your answers guys using the "uniqid" option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For solving this, we can generate the new file name which will be unique to save the files. For that if we convert the current date & time using strtotime(), the string generated will be unique and there is no chance for getting repeated file names. We can save the files with that name

```
if ($_GET['ul'] == 1) {
$target_path = "../uploads/documents/";

$fname = $_FILES['uploadfile1']['tmp_name'];
$filename = $_FILES['uploadfile1']['name'];

$extensions = array('xls','pdf','PDF','doc','DOC','docx','DOCX','jpg','JPG','xlsx');
$extension = strtolower( pathinfo( $filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );

if (in_array($extension, $extensions)) {
        $tempname = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

        $temp =explode(".",$fname);
        $target_path = $target_path.$tempname.'.'.$temp[1];
    move_uploaded_file($fname, $target_path);
    echo $filename;
} else {
    echo 'Sorry this file type cant be uploaded.';
}
}
```

Comment: where dot id missing?

Comment: Please add an explanation about what you've changed in the code and how it helps solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like this

```
    $f_name      = $_FILES['uploadfile1']['name'];
    $f_extension = explode('.', $f_name); //To breaks the string into array
   $f_extension = strtolower(end($f_extension)); //end() is used to retrun a last element to the array         
   $f_newfile = uniqid() . '.' . $f_extension; // / It`s use to stop overriding if the image will be same then uniqid() will generate the unique name of both file.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add timestamp to differentiate name of file

```
$fname = time() . '_' . $fname;
```

OR

```
$f_extension_array = explode('.', $f_name);
$f_extension = strtolower($f_extension_array[1]);
$fname = $f_extension_array[0] . '_' . time() . '.' . $f_extension;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use time() function to append timestamp in file name, because you can get unique value from time():

So it will be like:

```
$filename = time()."_".$_FILES['uploadfile1']['name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent files from overwriting eachother I always use the `uniqid()` function. This PHP function generates a unique id. If you append this id to your filename you will never have it overwriting some other file.

```
$filename = $filename.uniqid().$extension;
```